# Optimize iteration output to text file

Tags: python, optimization, iteration

I've written a piece of code which combines given letters in groups of *n* letters, and writes all the combinations in a text file. This is my first attempt and I wonder if there is an optimal way to do this.

```
letter_input = raw_input(' Type in letters: ')

number_input = int(raw_input(' Letters per word: '))

split_letters = list(letter_input)


def function():  

    all_combinations_list = list(itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input))

    output_file = open('/tmp/list.txt', 'w')

    number_of_combinations = len(all_combinations_list)

    for n in range(0,number_of_combinations):
        raw_characters = str(all_combinations_list[n])
        out_1 = raw_characters.translate(string.maketrans('',''), string.punctuation)
        out_2 = out_1.replace(' ','')
        print >>output_file, out_2


    output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't use global variable**

It make things hard to understand and to maintain. In your case, the simple way to do this is to feed your function `function()` the parameters it needs.

```
def function(letter_input, number_input, split_letters):
```

**Make your code easier to read**

You can ensure you respect [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the guideline to write Python code. You'll find various tools to help you comply to the usual standards : `pep8`,  `pylint`, `pyflakes`, `pychecker`.

Also, `function` is a pretty bad function name, let's pick something better (for instance `write_permutation`).

**Use pythonic loops**

Python provides you a clean/safe/concise/way to iterate over pretty much anything : `for something in something_iterable`. Using the loop index is much more verbose on top of being less efficient.

You can change :

```
all_combinations_list = list(itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input))
number_of_combinations = len(all_combinations_list)
for n in range(0,number_of_combinations):
    raw_characters = str(all_combinations_list[n])
```

to (using the default behavior for `range`)

```
all_combinations_list = list(itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input))
number_of_combinations = len(all_combinations_list)
for n in range(number_of_combinations):
    raw_characters = str(all_combinations_list[n])
```

then

```
all_combinations_list = list(itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input))
for e in all_combinations_list:
    raw_characters = str(e)
```

then

```
for e in list(itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input)):
    raw_characters = str(e)
```

then (because you don't need to create a temporary list) :

```
for e in itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input):
    raw_characters = str(e)
```

**Don't use complicated non-required logic**

Converting your tuple in a string you perform logic in in way too complicated on top of not being efficient.
You could just do something like (using what we call "tuple unpacking"):

```
for e in itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input):
    a, b, c = e
    out_2 = a+b+c
```

This can even be more concise by doing the unpacking as part of the loop :

```
for a, b, c in itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input):
    print >>output_file, a+b+c
```

**Using `with`**

You can use the `with` keyword to handle ressources that needs to be "opened" and "closed" such as files. In your case, you can write :

```
with open('/tmp/list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a, b, c in itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input):
        print >>f, a+b+c
```

and you don't need to close the file manually.

**Using the `if__name__` guard**

It is usually a good habit to put your code behind a guard to have your `main` code running only if we run your script and not if we import it (because one wants to re-use a function for instance).

**No need for `list` as strings are iterables too**

As pointed out in codesparkle's comment, you don't need to build a `list`.

Once this is done, you code looks like :

```
import itertools

def main():
    """Main function"""
    split_letters = raw_input(' Type in letters: ')
    number_input = int(raw_input(' Letters per word: '))
    with open('/tmp/list.txt', 'w') as f:
        for a, b, c in itertools.permutations(split_letters, number_input):
            print >>f, a+b+c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As a final note, your code could be written using a single call to `print` by using `join` on the list of permutations but this doesn't bring much so I'll skip that part.